# Finding a metric to write a vector field as a gradient of a given function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis, gradient-flows

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $f$ a smooth function with an isolated local minimum at $p$. Furthermore, let $X$ be a vector field vanishing at $p$ such that for some neighborhood $U$ of $p$, $df_q(X_q)<0$ for all $q\in U\setminus\{p\}$. Is it possible to find a Riemannian metric g on $U$ such that $X|_U=-\text{grad}_gf$? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: I think the answer should be no, in the same way not every 1-form is the differential of a function. However, since you allow to change the metric for each case... the answer is more difficult.

Comment: Do you know something about the order of vanishing at $p$? For example, if $f$ is Morse while $X$ vanishes at $p$ up to some high order, I believe your desired metric does not exist. However, if both $df$ and $X$ have a simple zero at $p$, there may be something you could do.

Comment: No, I would like a statement in full generality. So if there is one, any explicit counterexample of the kind you mention would be helpful.

Comment: What is your background in differential geometry? If you are comfortable with vector bundles and the notion of transversality, a fairly simple argument would help you construct many counterexamples.

Comment: I‘m comfortable with bundles, but do not know how to get started.

Comment: In the one-dimensional case this reduces to smooth divisibility of functions: $p=0,f=t^4, X=-t^2 \partial_t$ is a simple counterexample on $M=\mathbb R.$

Comment: Thanks you @Anthony for the simple counterexample! However, on $t<0$ the vector field points in the wrong direction, so I suppose the counterexample works on $M=[0,\infty)$ instead.

Comment: Or take $X=-t\partial_t$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I forgot about the derivative when choosing the signs. $-t \partial_t$ is the right choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, in general, is no.

The following is a general fact: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$, let $E\to M$ be a vector bundle of rank $n$, and let $s\in\Gamma(M,E)$ be a smooth section vanishing at $p\in M$. Let $\nabla$ be a linear connection on $E$. Then $s$ is transverse to the zero section at $p$ if and only if we have $$(\nabla_Xs)_p\neq0$$ for every $X\in T_pM$, $X\neq 0$, in other words, iff the endomorphism $X\mapsto(\nabla_Xs)_p$ is invertible.

Now, a Riemannian metric induces an isomorphism of vector bundles between the tangent and cotangent bundles. Transversality of sections is preserved under a bundle isomorphism. Suppose $f$ is Morse. In particular, the Hessian $\nabla^2f$ is non-degenerate at $p$, where $\nabla$ can be any linear connection on $TM$, or equivalently, the section $df$ of the cotangent bundle is transverse to the zero section at $p$. Take any vector field $X$ which vanishes at $p$ and which is not transverse to the zero section. Then no bundle isomorphism carries $X$ to $df$.

Comment: This looks like a very powerful and beautiful argument! I will study it in a bit more detail later. Thanks!